# ClickOnce Installation from URL still tries to download vsto file locally

Tags: vsto, clickonce, setup-deployment

I try to deploy my VSTO AddIn using ClickOnce with the following setup. When I start setup the installer still tries to find the vsto file in the users download folder instead of downloading it from the server.
This is the detailed error message:
Name:
Von: file:///C:/Users/myname/Downloads/myapp_OutlookPlugin.vsto

************** Ausnahmetext **************
System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: 'file:///C:/Users/myname/Downloads/myapp_OutlookPlugin.vsto' konnte nicht gedownloadet werden. ---> System.Net.WebException: Die Datei "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\myapp_OutlookPlugin.vsto" konnte nicht gefunden werden. ---> System.Net.WebException: Die Datei "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\myapp_OutlookPlugin.vsto" konnte nicht gefunden werden. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Die Datei "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\myapp_OutlookPlugin.vsto" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
bei System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
bei System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
bei System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
bei System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
bei System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
--- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
bei System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
bei System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
--- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
bei System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
bei System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
bei System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
--- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

[image]

Signing the deployment is configured like this:
[image]

And yes I made sure that the files are available on the server in the right directory. I verified this by manually downloading the vsto file from the webserver. It succeeded.

Comment: Did you try to install it in IE?

Comment: You may find a similar thread helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172284/clickonce-installation-failed-when-trying-to-deploy-files-to-be-downloaded

Comment: were you running the setup from the users' downloads folder or from the server? Did you find a solution to your problem? It would be beneficial if you can answer your question as other users might be having similar issues too.